# Restoration of gender balance after wars - what principle underlies this?

Tags: population, demography

I am wondering what is the statistical principle that underlies the following observation.

After every war in history, the male population of a given region would severely decline, tipping the male/female ratio from its usual (roughly) 50/50% to one that favours females by a more-or-less dramatic difference. Still, it seems to me that this balance somehow always picks up on its own, such that in a relatively short period, the gender ratio becomes balanced again. I haven't looked up the numbers, but I believe that in post-war Germany, it didn't take more than half a decade for the balance to reach 50/50 again. That's very short when compared to an average 25 years per generation.

Obviously, even if people specifically wanted to re-establish the gender balance, this could only be done by increasing male natality or/and increasing female mortality, none of which is possible/desireable. Yet, it seems the balance is restored whether people want to or not.

Rather than being a series of coincidences, I'd bet there is a statistical explanation for this phenomenon. What comes to my mind is the principle of regression to the mean, however that doesn't seem to be a good explanation, since the "extreme values" initially encountered were not part of random sampling but were due to an external - and biased - change at the level of the population, namely increased male mortality in wars.

Comment: What comes to *my* mind is that you should double check these "facts", which are likely mere legends.

Comment: The "obviously ,,, could only be done" statement is incorrect. Gender rebalance can easily be accomplished solely by *natural mortality*: the surviving women grow old and are gone within two generations.  There's not much of a "statistical principle" behind this ... .

Comment: Please show some actual (sourced) numbers that you think need explanation; I don't think it's reasonable to be expected to explain a phenomenon we cannot even *see*, merely on your claim that in one case it only took "half a decade". How would we know your claim is accurate?

Comment: Completely unhelpful comments, I did make it clear that the question was about the general phenomenon of gender balance restoration, which fortunately other contributors have addressed more relevantly below

Comment: Mightn't the fast restoration of sex ratio balance in post-war Germany (if there was such) be largely due to POWs returning home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there's no statistical trick at play, beyond the fact that older generation are replaced with newer ones and the law of large numbers. However, there is evidence that there are biological mechanisms at play, for instance:

[Evolutionary ecology of human birth sex ratio under the compound influence of climate change, famine, economic crises and wars](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2009.01598.x/abstract;jsessionid=23E4A5695654EAD5A1D6D2E4E81BD865.f01t01)

or

[Trends in Population Sex Ratios May be Explained by Changes in the Frequencies of Polymorphic Alleles of a Sex Ratio Gene](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11692-008-9046-3)

Comment: Thanks! This conclusion of one of the papers nicely sums up the likely explanation: "exogenous challenges like ambient temperature and war can skew human birth sex ratio"

Comment: @wildetudor: Hard to see how effects on birth sex ratio of the magnitude discussed in that paper - half a percentage point or so - could make much contribution to restoring a "dramatic" imbalance in population sex ratio within five years. To continue with the Germany example: with a population of about 70 million, there should have been about 5 million births in the five post-war years. Allowing for a large shift in birth sex ratio from 1.04 to 1.11 gives only 70 thousand additional male births, which wouldn't go far towards plugging any significant gap.

Answer (score 4):

Gender-ratio homeostasis would explain some, [here's one paper](https://origins.asu.edu/sites/default/files/Gender%20Imbalances%20In%20History--Causes,%20Consequences%20And%20Social%20Adjustment,%20by%20David%20T.%20Courtwright-PIIS1472648310603975.pdf) on the subj. There are several mechanisms such as migration, gene passing + Darwin selection etc.

Also, the restoration of gender balance was not so quick in the past as you make it sound. It took generations.

Comment: THanks. As I said, I haven't checked the figures (e.g. how many years it took for the gender balance to be restored in Europe) but was just wondering what the general phenomenon was, qualitatively, which the paper you linked to hints at.